# Atom search wildcard Fuzzy Find Files

Tags: atom-editor

Is there away to search for files using wildcard with the Fuzzy Find Files in Atom (cmd-t cmd-p)

e.g.
*query.js

shows
jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl+F`and then `Ctrl+Alt+/` for regex search

https://discuss.atom.io/t/search-wildcards-for-find-replace/16928

Answer (score -2):

the key cmd-b will make a wildcard search

Comment: Does not work. This opens the fuzzy-finder buffer finder, which will only find open files.